# LED with A/C Input

Tags: led

I've got a little problem.  I've got a house with a lit address number.  All the homes in the subdivision have the same device.  Doggone thing is wired up 27 volts A/C and is wired for two incandescent bulbs in series.  Bulbs don't last long.  The homeowners association insists everyone keep these displays operational.

I'd like to put some LED's in there.  It doesn't have to be crazy bright, the sign has to be simply illuminated. My goal is to have something with low power draw, and long life.

Any recommendations on how to proceed?

--Do I just add a rectifier, then place a few strands of LED's in series with appropriate resistance to create safe current flow and account for all voltage drops?

--What happens to a LED diode in an A/C circuit?... does it just 'flash' 60 times per second at 'half' illumination intensity or is that a really bad idea?

--Or am I better off finding a decent low power AC to DC converter chip and move along from there?

Comment: One issue with individual LEDs is that they tend to be fairly directional. It may be hard to get even lighting of the translucent front surface (assuming these units are what I'm thinking of).

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add a diode (rated at the right current) and leave the lights as they are - they'll be dimmer and quite possibly last longer (possibly not true for halogen). The idea of the diode is that the bulbs will be delivered with 50% of the power they had previously because the diode will block 50% of the power.

If it doesn't improve the lamps life then proceed with the LEDs - you'll need to choose LEDs that match the bulbs intensity (or half the intensity) and choose the appropriate current limiting device. The current limiting device may also need to be a switch mode regulator to prevent overheating and failure of that.

Comment: Its funny, there are good requirements and then there are the real requirements for most situations in life. In this case the real requirement is keep the Home Owners Association (HOA) off my back.  For that, there is a huge variance in lumens required. One step up from "discernible from the street at night" is fine with me. I'd like to reduce current draw to that point.  I would think four small LED's would work fine.

Comment: Putting a diode in series with an incandescent bulb(s) is the classic way to increase lifetime at the expense of brightness. It is (or was) commonly used in things like illuminated EXIT signs. It's the least-effort approach - give it a try.

Comment: I can certainly do that,but isn't that exactly the same as going to a low wattage bulb to increase bulb life?  Part of my problem is the 27 volt thing.  Most bulbs with the plugin socket I'm using are 12 volt bulbs... oops. they are in series, so that's okay...